# debuild - Is it possible to create several debian packages with different names from one sources adding specific option

Tags: debian, deb, dpkg-buildpackage

I create debian packages using debuild.

one by command with variable for one target type:

`debuild --set-envvar=TARGET=S_SS -b -us -uc -aarm64`

another one for another one

`debuild --set-envvar=TARGET=S_TT -b -us -uc -aarm64`

This variable is used in Makefile.

Result of debuild compilation is the *.deb with the same package name for both cases. Is it possible to set **specific package name** or **path to folder** with necessary for compilation files (I mean control, changelog and etc.) different form **default "debian"** ?

Comment: So the question is not about package name, but about directory called `debian`? Or just to create several binary packages from one source? But this is standard. So I'm confused what do you ask. In any case. `debian` directory must not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

the `debian/` folder (that contains all the the packaging stuff for Debian) is hard-coded into the Debian packaging tools.
you cannot easily switch it around.

having said that:
you can of course create multiple different binary packages, by declaring them in `debian/control` (and then adding the proper runes to `debian/rules` and accompanying configuration files, to declare which files should go into which package).
this is all explained in depth in the various Debian packaging tutorials (and owuld be out-of-scope here in StackOverflow.

- `apt install packaging-tutorial`
- https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html
- https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

> This variable is used in Makefile.

this is usually the wrong approach.
Debian packages are built from source package, so they are conceptually "downstream" consumers of your build-system.
in general you should not attempt to mix the two stages (building your software; packaging your software) into a single build system.

see https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide